# Элементы RecyclerView не меняются

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

я создаю активность в виде чата с помощью RecyclerView. Сообщения от другого пользователя должны отображаться слева, а сообщения от текущего пользователя - справа. Для этого я сделал две разметки для обоих типов:
Разметка для "левого" сообщения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="6dp">
    <!--разметка-->
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Разметка для "правого" сообщения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
android:layout_gravity="right">
    <!--разметка-->
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Отличие здесь только в layout_gravity.

Код моего адаптера:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<Message> list;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
final int MY_MESSAGE = 0;
final int OWN_MESSAGE = 1;


public MessageAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<Message> messages) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext);
    this.list = messages;

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(list.get(position).my)
        return MY_MESSAGE;
    else
        return OWN_MESSAGE;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == MY_MESSAGE)
        return new ViewHolder.MyMessageViewHolder(FragmentMyMessageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                parent, false).getRoot());
    else
        return new ViewHolder.OwnMessageViewHolder(FragmentMessageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                parent, false).getRoot());
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(list.get(position));
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void bind(Message message){

    }

    static class MyMessageViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
        private final FragmentMyMessageBinding binding;
        public String text;
        public String name;
        public String date;
        public MyMessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = FragmentMyMessageBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
        public void bind(Message message){

            text = message.text;
            name = message.username;
            date = message.date;


            binding.text.setText(text);
            binding.name.setText(name);
            binding.date.setText(date);
        }

    }


    static class OwnMessageViewHolder extends ViewHolder{

        private final FragmentMessageBinding binding;
        public String text;
        public String name;
        public String date;
        public OwnMessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = FragmentMessageBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
        public void bind(Message message){
            text = message.text;
            name = message.username;
            date = message.date;


            binding.text.setText(text);
            binding.name.setText(name);
            binding.date.setText(date);
        }
    }

}
```

Для двух типов сообщений я создал два класса, наследующихся от базового ViewHolder.

Проблема: все сообщения все равно выводятся именно слева, хотя android studio в режиме "split" показывает разметку для "правого" сообщения именно в правой части экрана. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Где вы подгружаете эти разметки? Там xml разметки указан верно?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, да, я указываю разметку в методе onCreateViewHolder() в зависимости от viewType. `FragmentMessageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())` для сообщения из вне и то же самое, только класс FragmentMyMessageBinding для "своего" сообщения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не показали весь макет - поэтому неизвестно как его лучше настроить.
Атрибут `layout_gravity` задаёт выравнивание самого элемента относительно его контейнера, но стандартные `LayoutManager`-ры его не обрабатывают.
Нужно либо писать свой `LayoutManager`, либо обернуть разметку элемента в контейнер, поддерживающий выравнивание (например `FrameLayout`), задать ему ширину `match_parent`, а выравнивание задать контейнеру сообщения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right">
        <!--разметка-->
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Да, действительно, CardView достаточно поместить в контейнер, чтобы выравнивать его. Вы помогли мне, спасибо за ответ!